# Inherit static methods that call their derived parent's methods

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, static

I'm trying to write a logging class that would work like this:

```
Log.Info("Something happened");  

Log.Error("Something else happened");

Log.Debug("Yet another thing happened!");
```

It should be accessible from every part of the namespace and quick to write, so I thought it'd be best to make it static. That way one can avoid having to create an object just to log a message.

At this point it is sort of like Console.WriteLine();

However, I wanted it also to be able to have two different modes: LogToConsole and LogToFile.

Thus the following syntax would be the most convenient:

```
LogConsole.Info("This will display in the console");  

LogFile.Debug("This will be saved to a file");  

LogAll.Error("This will be saved to a file AND displayed in a console");
```

However, I realized that there could be an large amount of "modes" multiplied by a very large amount of "logtypes".

How could I do this efficiently, in a way that I only have to write each logtype method once and depending on the derived class that calls the method, action a happens or action b happens?

Ideally I would like to define all methods once, and then create the classes that inherit them. But, since they are static methods their behavior is always the same. I can't tell them: "Find out what your superclass is and execute that class' SaveLog() method".

I realize that this would all be very very easy with abstract classes, but then I'd have to create objects.

Is there any way I could do this in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: this is a description of many logger, like log4net or NLog (that i would recommand just because i use it), you should read their docs http://nlog-project.org/

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: `static` does a lot more than "Make it easier to use". It makes the class work as a singleton, this may have unforeseen consequences if you're not careful.

Comment: I think your after an abstract class, but you can't have abstract static classes so you're going to have to compromise on static or abstract. *I realize that this would all be very very easy with abstract classes, but then I'd have to create objects.* I mean "thems the breaks" if you want abstraction then your need to create instances. Is it really that hard to type the word `new`?

Comment: Liam: It's not really that difficult, but I want to learn if there's a way this can be done.

At this point I'm not so much interested in logging, but in learning how I can create an infinite amount of methods that can be inherited by an infinite amount of classes, they all behaving different depending on the class that inherited them. 

For example, the .ToString() method is inherited globally and can be overriden. How is that done?

Answer (score 0):

Like Boo, would also recommend a logger like log4net.

If you do want to write it yourself, I would recommend against static methods as they would inhibit your ability to test the classes / methods that call it. Instead, inject your ILogger interface to all classes that might need logging. Then separate the "mode" from the target, so you can inject a list of targets to your logger.

```
public interface ILogTarget
{
    void Save(string message);
}

public class LogToFile : ILogTarget
{
    public void Save(string message)
    {
        //
    }
}


public class LogToConsole : ILogTarget
{
    public void Save(string message)
    {
        //
    }
}

public interface ILogger
{
    void Debug(string message);
}

public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private readonly List<ILogTarget> _targets;
    private static Logger _logger;

    public Logger(List<ILogTarget> targets)
    {
        _targets = targets;
    }

    public void Debug(string message)
    {
        foreach (var target in _targets)
            target.Save($"Debug: {message}");
    }

}

public class TheClassThatMakesTheCall
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TheClassThatMakesTheCall(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void AMethod()
    {
        _logger.Debug("some message");
    }
}

//In your IoC, register Logger as a type of ILogger, and pass in the targets that you want
//If your target vary per situation, you'll need a ILogTarget factory that returns a different list of loggers based on the situation
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I'll have to take my time to understand it. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit from static classes. But you can get away with making only the functions static. don't make the classes as static. Just make the functions as static, then you can use the "new" keyword in the derived class. It would be something like this

```
// IF this is your base class
public class Log
{
    public static bool Info(string Message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Message + " From Log");
        return true;
    }

    public static bool Success(string Message)
    {

        return true;
    }

    public static bool Error(string Message)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

//Then this can be your derived class
public class LogFile : Log
{
    public static new bool Info(string Message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Message + " From LogFile");
        return true;
    }

    public static new bool Success(string Message)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static new bool Error(string Message)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't behave any differently than just *not* using inheritance at all.  Even though one class is inheriting from the other, it's shadowing every single method, resulting in there being no effect from the inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however the problem here is that you have to define or write a method for each possible logtype and just for the sake of learning I'm considering the possibility there might be a very large amount.

In the end I did what I attempted to by writing a Singleton and then a static class that calls the singleton. I haven't tested it thoroughly yet, but it should work :)